# Is it possible to test RTMFP on LAN or maybe through a VPN?

Tags: actionscript, udp, vpn, lan, rtmfp

We are building a Flash RTMFP application and our ISP blocks UDP communication.

The only method to test the application is for every developer to go home, and then perform the test, together.

Until now, this was okay, because we only implemended text-messaging, there is not much thing to test there...
But now, when we want to test video and audio transfer, (mainly quality), this is not an option.

Is it possible, to perform tests on LAN, or maybe not on LAN, but through a VPN service (my preference)? Will the ISP blocking still affect the VPN option?

Thank you for every answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course test RTMFP connections in your local network. Just set up a RTMFP server (like [Cumulus](https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus)) and connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it checks if from wherever you are on the internet (behind comapny firewalls, at home, etc) you can access an RTMFP service:

[RTMFP Connection Status](http://cc.rtmfp.net/)